# Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Cursor?

Tags: kotlin, filepath, android-cursor

And in IntelliJ the function onActivityResult is crossed out..

I'm trying to use cursor.getColumnIndex in the video Ive seen it works but here says Ive to initialize cursor.

What about these lines:

```
val cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedImage,filePathColum,null,null,null) 

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_CODE  && data!=null){
            val selectedImage=data.data
            val filePathColumn=arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedImage!!,filePathColumn,null,null,null)
           //cant use it here
            cursor.moveToFirst()
        }
        //and here                
        val columnIndex= cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the whole file

Comment: Just do as it says while accessing `cursor` use `cursor?.functionName()` if you are not sure weather it's null or `cursor!!.functionName()` if you are sure it's **NEVER** null

Answer (score 1):

You can just either add 2 exclamation marks to make it non-null asserted or wrap it with a let call.

`cursor!!.moveToFirst()`

or

`cursor?.moveToFirst()`